# How I can Stop Resizing and Cropping in following code?

Tags: php, image, crop, image-resizing

Here is the code which I am using to Resize my Images and I want to Stop resizing and Cropping...Here is the code which I am using to Resize my Images and I want to Stop resizing and Cropping...Here is the code which I am using to Resize my Images and I want to Stop resizing and Cropping...Here is the code which I am using to Resize my Images and I want to Stop resizing and Cropping...Here is the code which I am using to Resize my Images and I want to Stop resizing and Cropping...

```
   # ========================================================================#
   #
   #  Author:    Jarrod Oberto
   #  Version:   1.0
   #  Date:      17-Jan-10
   #  Purpose:   Resizes and saves image
   #  Requires : Requires PHP5, GD library.
   #  Usage Example:
   #                     include("classes/resize_class.php");
   #                     $resizeObj = new resize('images/cars/large/input.jpg');
   #                     $resizeObj -> resizeImage(150, 100, 0);
   #                     $resizeObj -> saveImage('images/cars/large/output.jpg', 100);
   #
   #
   # ========================================================================#


    Class resize
    {
        // *** Class variables
        private $image;
        private $width;
        private $height;
        private $imageResized;

        function __construct($fileName)
        {
            // *** Open up the file
            $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

            // *** Get width and height
            $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
            $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function openImage($file)
        {
            // *** Get extension
            $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

            switch($extension)
            {
                case '.jpg':
                case '.jpeg':
                    $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                    break;
                case '.gif':
                    $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                    break;
                case '.png':
                    $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                    break;
                default:
                    $img = false;
                    break;
            }
            return $img;
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
        {
            // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
            $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

            $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


            // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, 
            $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


            // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
            if ($option == 'crop') {
                $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
        {

           switch ($option)
            {
                case 'exact':
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    break;
                case 'portrait':
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    break;
                case 'landscape':
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    break;
                case 'auto':
                    $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                    $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                    break;
                case 'crop':
                    $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                    $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                    break;
            }
            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
        {
            $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
            $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
            return $newWidth;
        }

        private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
        {
            $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
            $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
            return $newHeight;
        }

        private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
        {
            if ($this->height < $this->width)
            // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
            {
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
            }
            elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
            // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
            {
                $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            }
            else
            // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
            {
                if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                } else {
                    // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                }
            }

            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
        {

            $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
            $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

            if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
            } else {
                $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
            }

            $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
            $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
        {
            // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
            $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
            $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

            $crop = $this->imageResized;
            //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

            // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, 
            $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
        {
            // *** Get extension
            $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
            $extension = strtolower($extension);

            switch($extension)
            {
                case '.jpg':
                case '.jpeg':
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                        imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                    }
                    break;

                case '.gif':
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                        imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                    }
                    break;

                case '.png':
                    // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                    $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                    // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                    $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                         imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                    }
                    break;

                // ... etc

                default:
                    // *** No extension - No save.
                    break;
            }

            imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
        }


        ## --------------------------------------------------------

    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Don't...use this script? I mean..it's entirely just for resizing and cropping, and if you don't want either of those..then... **bangs head against wall**...

Comment: But When I try to remove this code, My entire website create errors and no image display..

Answer (score 0):

try to set image height and width null

```
 private $height='';
 private $width='';
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Main reason of Resizing is in this code

// *** Include the class
include("resize-class.php");

// *** 1) Initialise / load image
$resizeObj = new resize('sample.jpg');

// *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(150, 100, 'crop');

// *** 3) Save image
$resizeObj -> saveImage('sample-resized.gif', 100);

I cnage the size of 150, 100 to my actual size and proble solved......